# React native IOS, when TextInput is focused, button press does not register

Tags: react-native

In react-native I have a TextInput element and when you click on it the keyboard pops up as desired. The problem however is that I have a arrow button that you click when you have entered your input into the TextInput but the first touch on the button or anywhere else always ONLY removes the keyboard and does not run the onPress function on the arrow button. How do I make it so that when I have entered my text and still have the keyboard up. The next press both removes the keyboard and also executes the onPress function on the button. Right now the user has to double press. Once to remove the keyboard and then the second time the function for onPress is executing.

```
<View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: "#b70f42", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
  <View style={{position: "relative"}}>
    <TextInput
      style={{color: "#FFF", borderBottomColor: "#FFF", borderBottomWidth: 1,fontSize:30,padding: 0, paddingRight: 50,height: 40,width: this.state.width*3/4,shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 }, shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 0.5, shadowRadius: 5}}
      onChangeText={(passwordInput) => this.showArrow(passwordInput)}
      value={this.state.passwordInput}
      placeholder="Vart ska du?"
      placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
    />
    <Text style={{marginLeft: 175,color:"#FFF"}}>Powered by IBM</Text>
    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="rgba(255,255,255,0)" style={{position: "absolute", top: 0, right: 5,}} onPress={() => this.onSearchButtonClick()}>
      <Animated.Image
        source={require("../../img/right-arrow.png")}
        style={{width:40, height: 40,opacity: this.state.arrowOpacity}}>
      </Animated.Image>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: hi, can  you provide the code, because i also faced this issue in past.

Comment: Hey thanks have added the code now @Prince

Comment: can you please provide the whole code, as TextInput alone can't describe the cause for the issue.

Comment: Please share how you write function `showArrow`

Comment: this is the whole component

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you wrap your `View` inside a `ScrollView`, then you can. `ScrollView` has a property called `keyboardShouldPersistTaps`.

> keyboardShouldPersistTaps Determines when the keyboard should stay
>   visible after a tap.
>
> 'never' (the default), tapping outside of the focused text input when
>   the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children
>   won't receive the tap.
>
> 'always', the keyboard will not dismiss
>   automatically, and the scroll view will not catch taps, but children
>   of the scroll view can catch taps.
>
> 'handled', the keyboard will not
>   dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by a children, (or
>   captured by an ancestor).

Use `handled`, so that the ScrollView can handle touches even when the keyboard is open. For your second question of closing keyboard onPress, import `Keyboard` from react-native and use `Keyboard.dismiss()` to close any open keyboard. Call this function inside your onPress.

For example,

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' >
  //Other Components

  <Button onPress={() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    //Your logic
  }}/>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer saved me, one thing I want to add is , if you are using nested layouts, do not try to wrap your textInput to a scrollview or your button as explained above answer, Instead try to find ,if you are using any scrollView in your view hierarchy and add the props there. the scrollView should be the parent to your textInput.

Comment: I had the same problem when use SectionList component with TextInput. But after added keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" - work perfectly.

Comment: FlatList also has this property: keyboardShouldPersistTaps